# What causes excessive anonymous method closures (c__DisplayClass1) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach, closures

Eqatec shows several thousand anonymous method closures being called each time a method is called that includes a simple LINQ 'Where' statement in my program. Pseudo code example:

```
Class1
{
    //foo and bar are both EF model classes
    List<foo> aList; // n = 2000
    List<bar> bList; // n = ~4000

    void aMethod() 
    {  
        foreach (var item in aList)
        {
            Class2.DoSomeWork(item, bList);
        }
    }
}

Class2
{
    static void DoSomeWork(foo item, List<bar> bList)
    {
     var query = bList.where(x => x.prop1 == item.A && x.prop2 = item.B).toList(); // <--- Calls thousands of anonymous method closures each method call.

     if (query.any()) <--- Calls only 1 anonymous method closure.
        DoSomethingElse(); 
    } 
}
```

I don't understand why 2,000 calls to 'DoSomeWork' called some 8 million anonymous method closures (even 1 causes several thousand).

As a fix, I simply rewrote the statement without using LINQ which eliminated the need for closures and produced a 10x fold increase in performance.

I would still like to understand why this occurred in the first place if anyone has some theories they would like to share.

Comment: Do you mean "creates 8M objects"? or do you mean "calls a method 8M times" ? The code you post (after sanitizing it so it compiles) ***does not*** create 8M objects - it causes 2000, which is what we would expect (via `aList`). If you are referring to object creation, I think you've changed things during copy/paste/sanitize. I do not think the scenario now represents what you are seeing. Can you post something closer to the original, that ideally a: compiles, and b: shows the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the 8M is referring to the number of times a method was executed on a closure class, and *not* the number of closure instances created. Firstly, let's make the code compile:

```
class Class2
{
    public static void DoSomeWork(foo item, List<bar> bList)
    {
        var query = bList.Where(x => x.prop1 == item.A && x.prop2 == item.B)
                         .ToList();

        if (query.Any())
            DoSomethingElse();
    }
    static void DoSomethingElse() { }
}
class foo { public int A { get; set; } public int B { get; set; } }
class bar { public int prop1 { get; set; } public int prop2 { get; set; } }
```

Now, we can discard the original " // <--- Calls only 1 anonymous method closure." comment, because actually **no** anonymous method closures are used by the `.Any()` - that just checks whether a list has contents: no closures required.

Now; let's manually rewrite the closure to show what is happening in the compiler:

```
class Class2
{
    class ClosureClass
    {
        public foo item; // yes I'm a public field
        public bool Predicate(bar x)
        {
            return x.prop1 == item.A && x.prop2 == item.B;
        }
    }
    public static void DoSomeWork(foo item, List<bar> bList)
    {
        var ctx = new ClosureClass { item = item };
        var query = bList.Where(ctx.Predicate).ToList();

        if (query.Any()) {
            DoSomethingElse();
        }
    }
    static void DoSomethingElse() { }
}
```

You can see that 1 `ClosureClass` is created per `DoSomeWork`, which maps directly to how the only captured variable (`item`) is scoped at the method level. The *predicate* (`ctx.Predicate`) is obtained **once** (only), but is invoked for every item in `bList`. So indeed, 2000 * 4000 is 8M calls to a method; however, 8M calls to a method is not necessarily slow.

However! I think the biggest problem is that you are creating a new list just to check for existence. You don't need that. You can make your code **much** more efficient by moving the `Any` earlier:

```
if (bList.Any(x => x.prop1 == item.A && x.prop2 == item.B)) {
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

This now only invokes the predicate enough times until a match is found, which we should anticipate to be less than all of them; it also doesn't fill a list unnecessarily.

Now; *yes*, it will be be *a bit* more efficient to do this manually, i.e.

```
bool haveMatch = false;
foreach(var x in bList) {
    if(x.prop1 == item.A && x.prop2 == item.B) {
        haveMatch = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(haveMatch) {
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

but note that this change between `Any` and `foreach` is *not* the critical difference; the **critical** difference is that I've removed the `ToList()` and the "keep reading, even if you've already found a match". The `Any(predicate)` usage is a lot more concise and is easy to read etc. It isn't typically a performance issue, and I doubt it is here either.

Comment: The original 'query' was an IEnumerable<bar>, I don't know why I made it a List here. I don't know why I assumed the "DisplayClass" was being created and not simply accessed. This was an outstanding answer and helped clear up my misunderstandings. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In the line

```
var query = bList.where(x => x.prop1 == item.A && x.prop2 = item.B).toList();
```

with bList having 4000 elements,  `x => x.prop1 == item.A && x.prop2 = item.B` is going to be called 4000 times. If you want the `.Any()` to be evaluated lazily, remove the `.ToList()`.